# dpkg: error processing archive udev_237-3ubuntu10.23_amd64.deb (--install)

Tags: dpkg, udev

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.
After regular apt update/upgrade I have the following error:

```
apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 237-3ubuntu10.22) but 237-3ubuntu10.23 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried `apt --fix-broken install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-50 linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-50-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-50-generic
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  udev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  udev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,102 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 169148 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../udev_237-3ubuntu10.23_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udev (237-3ubuntu10.23) over (237-3ubuntu10.22) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_237-3ubuntu10.23_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to stat './etc/udev/hwdb.d' (which I was about to install): Bad message
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_237-3ubuntu10.23_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As well as `dpkg -i --force-overwrite udev_237-3ubuntu10.23_amd64.deb`:

```
(Reading database ... 169148 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack udev_237-3ubuntu10.23_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udev (237-3ubuntu10.23) over (237-3ubuntu10.22) ...
dpkg: error processing archive udev_237-3ubuntu10.23_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to stat './etc/udev/hwdb.d' (which I was about to install): Bad message
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev_237-3ubuntu10.23_amd64.deb
```

Please help, how to solve it...

Comment: In my opinion there is a mistake in the package: it want to use /etc/udev/hwdb.d but has a "." before the path (= "./etc/udev/hwdb.d"). If you do not have this directory in /etc/udev (without the "./") create it with `mkdir -p /etc/udev/hwdb.d`.

Comment: `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'` Other packages are involved too. 22 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.

Comment: My file system was corrupted. So, all the problems were going from there.
I backed up my data and reinstalled everything.